# Issue in using PyQt and beautiful soup together for webscraping

Tags: python-2.7, onclick, pyqt, screen-scraping

I am using combination of PyQt and beautiful soup to scrape data from a webpage. PyQt is being used as a interpreter between Python and Javascript. I am invoking a "onclick" event and trying to feed that html after "click" event to Beautiful soup. Below is the referred code:

```
import csv
import urllib2
import sys
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from PyQt4.QtGui import *  
from PyQt4.QtCore import *  
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *  

class Render(QWebPage):  
  def __init__(self, url):  
    self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
    QWebPage.__init__(self)  
    self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)  
    self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))  
    self.app.exec_()  

  def _loadFinished(self, result):  
    self.frame = self.mainFrame()  
    self.app.quit()  

url = 'http://www.att.com/shop/wireless/devices/smartphones.html'  
r = Render(url)
jsClick = """var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
             evObj.initEvent('click', true, true );
             this.dispatchEvent(evObj);
             """

allSelector = "a#deviceShowAllLink" 
allButton   = r.frame.documentElement().findFirst(allSelector)
allButton.evaluateJavaScript(jsClick) 
html = allButton.frame.toHtml()


page = html
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
soup.prettify()
with open('Smartphones_26decv2.0.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    spamwriter.writerow(["Date","Day of Week","Device Name","Price"])
    items = soup.findAll('a', {"class": "clickStreamSingleItem"},text=True)
    prices = soup.findAll('div', {"class": "listGrid-price"})
    for item, price in zip(items, prices):
        textcontent = u' '.join(price.stripped_strings)
        if textcontent:            
            spamwriter.writerow([time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),time.strftime("%A") ,unicode(item.string).encode('utf8').strip(),textcontent])
```

Now after running this, I am getting below mentioned error:

```
File "D:\Microsoft\Pricing\2012-12-26\AT&T_attempt2code.py", line 32, in <module>
    html = allButton.frame.toHtml()
AttributeError: 'QWebElement' object has no attribute 'frame'
```

Please help me in resolving this issue and pardon my ignorance as I am new to programming.

Comment: This is a pyqt *only* problem, nothing to do with BeautifulSoup.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for suggestion, tags changed accordingly. Can you help me in solving this PyQt problem? I am in urgent need to solve this.

Comment: sorry, no experience with QWebElement myself.

Comment: Can you guide this problem to someone who may help me in resolving this.

Comment: That's what tags are for. And patience. It's the Christmas holidays, so it could take a little longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the error message the problem is in the line:

```
html = allButton.frame.toHtml()
```

`allButton` doesn't have a `frame` attribute because it is an instance of `QWebElement` (the sequence of transformations on its definition is `Render` -> `QWebFrame` -> `QWebElement` -> `QWebElement`).

In your code the `frame` attribute is defined in the `Render._loadFinished` method so only the `r` object has a `frame` attribute.

You can get rid of the error if you change your `html` definition to:

```
html = r.frame.toHtml()
```

or to:

```
html = allButton.webFrame().toHtml()
```

Comment: I tried using this `html = allButton.webFrame().toHtml()`. I am not getting any error but output which I am getting is only for 18 default items which are visible by default on this webpage. I am using PyQt and evaluateJavascript to invoke onclick event for showing all devices on webpage so that I am able to extract data for all devices. Please go through the above code and help me in solving this.

Comment: Let's do things properly. If, as it seems, this answer has been useful to you then please upvote/accept it. In order to get help with your **new problem** you should publicize it creating a **new question** with a descriptive title so that other SO users can see it and participate in the search of the solution.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have made the new problem @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050585/issue-in-invoking-onclick-event-using-pyqt-javascript Please go through it