# Issue in invoking "onclick" event using PyQt & javascript

Tags: javascript, css, python-2.7, pyqt, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from a website using beautiful soup. By default, this webpage shows 18 items and after clicking on a javascript button "showAlldevices" all 41 items are visible. Beautiful soup scrapes data only for items visible by default, to get data for all items I used PyQt module and invoked the click event using the javascript code. Below is the referred code:

```
import csv
import urllib2
import sys
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from PyQt4.QtGui import *  
from PyQt4.QtCore import *  
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *  

class Render(QWebPage):  
  def __init__(self, url):  
    self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
    QWebPage.__init__(self)  
    self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)  
    self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))  
    self.app.exec_()  

  def _loadFinished(self, result):  
    self.frame = self.mainFrame()  
    self.app.quit()  

url = 'http://www.att.com/shop/wireless/devices/smartphones.html'  
r = Render(url)
jsClick = """var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
             evObj.initEvent('click', true, true );
             this.dispatchEvent(evObj);
             """

allSelector = "a#deviceShowAllLink" 
allButton   = r.frame.documentElement().findFirst(allSelector)
allButton.evaluateJavaScript(jsClick) 
html = allButton.webFrame().toHtml()


page = html
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
soup.prettify()
with open('Smartphones_26decv2.0.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    spamwriter.writerow(["Date","Day of Week","Device Name","Price"])
    items = soup.findAll('a', {"class": "clickStreamSingleItem"},text=True)
    prices = soup.findAll('div', {"class": "listGrid-price"})
    for item, price in zip(items, prices):
        textcontent = u' '.join(price.stripped_strings)
        if textcontent:            
            spamwriter.writerow([time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),time.strftime("%A") ,unicode(item.string).encode('utf8').strip(),textcontent])
```

I am feeding the html to beautiful soup by using this line of code `html = allButton.webFrame().toHtml()` This code is running without any errors **but I am still not getting data for all 41 items in the output csv**

I also tried feeding html to beautiful soup using these lines of code:

```
allButton   = r.frame.documentElement().findFirst(allSelector)
a = allButton.evaluateJavaScript(jsClick) 
html = a.webFrame.toHtml()


page = html
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
```

But I came across this error: `html = a.webFrame.toHtml()
AttributeError: 'QVariant' object has no attribute 'webFrame'`

Please pardon my ignorance if I am asking anything fundamental here, as I am new to programming and help me in solving this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a problem with your JavaScript code. Since you're creating a `MouseEvent` object you should use an `initMouseEvent` method for initialization. You can find an example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.dispatchEvent).

**UPDATE2**

But I think the simplest think you can try is to use the JavaScript DOM method `onclick` of the `a` element instead of using your own JavaScript code. Something like this:

```
allButton.evaluateJavaScript("this.onclick()")
```

should work. I suppose you will have to reload the page after clicking, before passing it to the parser.

**UPDATE 3**

You can reload the page via `r.action(QWebPage.ReloadAndBypassCache)` or `r.action(QWebpage.Reload)` but it doesn't seem to have any effect. I've tried to display the page with `QWebView`, click the link and see what happens. Unfortunately I'm getting lots of Segmentation Fault errors so I would swear there is a bug somewhere in PyQt4/Qt4. As the page being scrapped uses jquery I've also tried to display it after loading jquery in the `QWebPage` but again no luck (the segfaults do not disappear). I'm giving up :( I hope other users here at SO will help you. Anyway I recommend you to ask for help to [the PyQt4 mailing list](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/mailman/listinfo/pyqt). They provide excellent support to PyQt users.

**UPDATE**

The error you get when changing your code is expected: remember that `allButton` is a `QWebElement` object. And the `QWebElement.evaluateJavaScript` method returns a `QVariant` object (as stated in [the docs](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qwebelement.html#evaluateJavaScript)) and that kind of objects don't have a `webFrame` attribute as you can check reviewing [this page](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qvariant.html).

Comment: I tried changing it to `initMouseEvent` but output csv is still giving list of 18 items visible by default on webpage

Comment: **Update 2** Tried using `this.onclick()` just now, still getting output for only 18 items visible by default

Comment: Even if you reload the page after clicking?

Comment: Yeah, how do I reload the page? I think Parser is not getting the post "onclick" event page.

Comment: It is explained in my last update. Try it, maybe you will be more lucky than I. Please, let me know if it works for you. Sorry for not being of more help.

Comment: Thanks! You have been a great help. After reading about your doubts regarding PyQt I researched more and came acroos this firebug addon for firefox. I used it to find the link for html page which is actually being pulled out when we are clicking that button. I parsed that html directly with beautiful soup & got the data for all 41 items. Yay! :)